# Hapi.js response with "type":"Buffer"

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js, hapi.js

I have hapi.js,  sequelize with mysql with script like this :

```
method: 'GET',
      path: `/${GROUP_NAME}`,
      options: {
        tags: ['api', GROUP_NAME],
        description: 'Mendapatkan jumlah tempat tidur berdasarkan kelas',
        notes: 'Mendapatkan jumlah tempat tidur',
        handler: async (request, h) => {
          return jlhttidurbyjenis.findAll({ attributes: ['VIP','KELAS 1','KELAS 2','KELAS 3','ICU','NICU','PICU','HCU','ICCU','ISOLASI']})
        },
    validate: {

    },
    response: {

    }
  }
```

when I test with postman it response like this :

```
[
    {
        "VIP": {
            "type": "Buffer",
            "data": [
                50,
                47,
                50,
                50
            ]
        },
        "KELAS 1": {
            "type": "Buffer",
            "data": [
                48,
                47,
                48
            ]
        },
        "KELAS 2": {
            "type": "Buffer",
            "data": [
                48,
                47,
                48
            ]
        },
        "KELAS 3": {
            "type": "Buffer",
            "data": [
                48,
                47,
                48
            ]
        },
        "ICU": {
            "type": "Buffer",
            "data": [
                48,
                47,
                48
            ]
        },
        "NICU": {
            "type": "Buffer",
            "data": [
                48,
                47,
                48
            ]
        },
        "PICU": {
            "type": "Buffer",
            "data": [
                48,
                47,
                48
            ]
        },
        "HCU": {
            "type": "Buffer",
            "data": [
                48,
                47,
                48
            ]
        },
        "ICCU": {
            "type": "Buffer",
            "data": [
                48,
                47,
                48
            ]
        },
        "ISOLASI": {
            "type": "Buffer",
            "data": [
                48,
                47,
                48
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

How to fix the script so the response will be the same with database content, it will be like this :

```
[
{
    "VIP": "12/22",
    "KELAS 1": "0/0",
    "KELAS 2": "0/0",
    "KELAS 3": "0/0",
    "ICU": "0/0",
    "NICU": "0/0",
    "PICU": "0/0",
    "HCU": "0/0",
    "ICCU": "0/0",
    "ISOLASI": "0/0"
    }
```

]

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a serialization issue from sequilize. Look at available configurations for JSON serialization with regards to buffer.

Comment: it should be a comment.